# How to create leases to avoid duplicate cron-jobs when deploying application across multiple instances?

Tags: docker, cron

I have a Dockerized Django application which have a number of CRON-jobs that need to be executed.

Right now I'm running it with the package Supercronic (which is recommended for running cron-jobs inside containers). This will be deployed on a two servers for redunancy-purposes, i.e. If one goes down the other one need to take over and execute the cron-jobs.

However, the issue is that without any configuration this will result in duplicate cron-jobs being executed, one for each server. I've read that you can set up something called a "lease" for the cron-jobs to retrieve, to avoid duplicates from different servers, but I haven't found any instructions on how to set this up.

Can someone maybe point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Supercron in two different instance, Supercron doesn't know about whether the job gets triggered, **Its up to the application to handle the consistency**.

You can do it in many ways either controlling the state with File or DB entries or any better way where your docker application can check the status before it start executing the actual process.

Comment: Can you give me a good example of how practically check the status of the process? Having a DB entry of each cron process finishing feels hacky, but that's maybe the best way to do it.